# Hyperlink in Lightbox Gallery

Tags: jquery, html, css, hyperlink, lightbox

I have a lightbox gallery here: www.hrmny.co.uk (click on portfolio)

I want it so that when a photo is clicked, the caption underneath is a hyperlink to another website.

Could someone advise on the code needed for this as the usual  doesn't seem to be working for me as it seems to get rid of the title all together?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have had a look at the documentation and source code for poptrox, your lightbox plugin and cannot see a convenient way to pass html to the caption in order to create the link, as it uses the contents of the image title attribute at the moment.

On line 606 of the poptrox (non-minified) code on [GitHub](https://github.com/n33/jquery.poptrox/blob/master/jquery.poptrox.js) is the line where it sets the caption text using `captionText: i.attr('title'),`, if you replace this with `captionText: $.parseHTML(i.attr('title')),`, then jQuery will parse the content of the title attribute as html instead of plain text. You also need to set the title attributes for each image to `title="<a href='link/to/site'>CAPTION TITLE</a>"` instead of just being CAPTION TITLE as it is now. Note the single quotation marks around the link but the double marks around the whole title attribute. You will also have to serve the modified version of poptrox from your server.

Comment: No problem, on a related note, I would recommend that you serve your jQuery file from the Google CDN at https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide by putting `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>` in the head instead of the same file on your own server, it is faster and reduces bandwidth use on your server. If my solution has worked could you accept my answer so that it may help others. Thanks